# Why did my seeds not germinate?

Tags: seeds, germination, hibiscus

I had planted roselle 6 days back in cocopeat sterilised by boiling for 15 minutes then keeping it to cool. The seeds were soaked in water for 3 hours. But so far, none of these have germinated. The seeds are an year old. I have had successful germination two three times back during the last two to three months. I have kept these in shade with indirect sunlight. Temperatures hovering around 23~40 degrees celsius. The trays were first cleaned with detergent then soaked in a solution of Dettol then washed off thoroughly with water.  [image]

Comment: Btw, those pots look really wet. Did you just water them prior to taking the picture?

Comment: Yes. I watered them just before taking the picture.

Comment: Roselle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roselle_(plant)

Answer (score 1):

A quick web search shows that roselle has a germination time of **seven to fifteen days**. This fits your own observation where a previous batch needed [“eight days or so”](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/57101) So after six days, it’s **too early** to assume that your seeds didn’t germinate.

If you didn’t slightly sand down or nick the seeds to accelerate water hydrating the seed, your germination time will probably be on the longer side anyway.

Comment: Probably the seeds which I got dropped in my hand from the packet were not the good ones. There were 6 of them and 3 of them were floating. None germinated, it has been so long.